# Headless use of open office or libreoffice in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: libreoffice, headless, openoffice

I want to install openoffice headless in Ubuntu 14.10, but when I try to install it, it says there is no package for that name.

I installed `libreoffice-common` using `apt-get`, but I can't find headless.

How can I install Openoffice headless?

Comment: Did you try that instruction? http://askubuntu.com/a/197687/295017

Answer (score 6):

The package `libreoffice-common` is right - there is no longer a separate package it's just a command line option you need: `--headless`:

`libreoffice --headless ...`

For the headless use in general, which did not change much,
see [@AnwarShah on Install OpenOffice for headless use](https://askubuntu.com/a/197687/295017)